# Convergence of the sum of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative random variables such that for each n, $X_n$ has density $\lambda_n e^{-\lambda_n x}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $\lambda_n > 0$

i) Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 /\lambda_n < \infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n < \infty$ almost surely

ii) If the $\{X_n\}$ are independent, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/\lambda_n < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n < \infty$ almost surely

I proved the first implication ($\Rightarrow$) of ii) using the three series of Kolmogorov, but I can't figure out the converse. Also, I have no idea how to solve i) without independence (since my only idea was to use the three series of Kolmogorov).

This is exercise 11.29 on Leadbetter, Cambanis *a basic course in Measure and Probability*.

I would appreciate any hint or help

EDIT: I think I figured the solution out, this is my attempt:

$(\Leftarrow$

Let $X_n'$ be equal to $X_n$ when $X_n \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise.
Then we have that
$P(X_n > 1) = \int_1^\infty \lambda_n e^{-\lambda_nx}dx = e^{-\lambda_n}$

But by Three series of Kolmogorov (since $\sum X_n$ converges a.s.), it results that $\sum e^{-\lambda_n} < \infty$ which implies that $\lambda_n \to \infty$, hence $1/\lambda_n \to 0$

Now, considering the expectation of $X_n'$ we get that

\begin{equation*}
    EX_n' = - e^{-\lambda_n} - \frac{1}{\lambda_n}e^{-\lambda_n} + \frac{1} 
    {\lambda_n}
\end{equation*}

Again, by Three series of Kolmogorov,
\begin{equation*}
   -\sum e^{-\lambda_n} + \sum \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \left( 1 - e^{-\lambda_n} 
   \right) < \infty
\end{equation*}
But since $\sum e^{-\lambda_n} < \infty$ and $1/\lambda_n \to 0$ we conclude that
\begin{equation*}
   \sum \frac{1}{\lambda_n} < \infty
\end{equation*}

Is this correct?

Comment: (i) follows from showing the expected value of the infinite sum is finite

Comment: You're so right. I hadn't thought about that little detail. Thanks!